# Creando UserControl iOS, error "framework not found GxFoundation" Genexus 17u8

Tags: ios, genexus, usercontrol

Estoy intentando migrar un UserControl que tenemos desarrollado y ahora con la 17u8 nos esta dando problemas, ya que implementa código que estarían deprecated
La idea es volverlo a desarrolloar para este upgrade, siguiendo los pasos detallados en la wiki, creo un nuevo proyecto "Gx Framework" y este me crea el proyecto y efectivamente se ven los Frameworks de Genexus para utilizar en el mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en XCode creo el Custom Paths tal cual como se pide:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ademas chequeo que en build Setting la prop "Frameworks Search Paths" este seteada de manera correcta :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo esto tal cual se indica en la documentación, pero pero pese a que todo esto parece estar ok, al momento de implementar y compilar el código, me falla el build ya y me tira que no encuentra los framworks de Gx:
[image: Error en Build]

[image: Error en Build]

Le he estado dando vueltas y no he dado con el problema, los folders existen, los frameworks existen en esos folders etc.
Cualquier comentario, será bienvenido.
Gracias